# What are the meaning of the simple directional arrow above the double arrows in this schematic?

Tags: schematics, protection, surge-protection, over-voltage-protection, single-phase

Helo,, I would like to know what are the simple directional arrows above the double arrows in this schematic?.

[image: Capture of the schematic]